# Hibernate One to One Unidirectional Primary key XML mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, mapping, one-to-one

I am trying to create one to one unidirectional primary key relation between two tables in hibernate.I am using the xml maaping.Following are my java POJO classes and their respective .hbm files.

Student POJO class

```
public class Student {

    private Long studentId;
    private String name;
    private Locker locker;

    public Long getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }
    public void setStudentId(Long studentId) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Locker getLocker() {
        return locker;
    }
    public void setLocker(Locker locker) {
        this.locker = locker;
    }
}
```

Student.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.avinash.dto.Student" table="STUDENT">
        <id name="studentId" type="long" column="STUDENT_ID">
            <generator class="native"></generator>
        </id>

        <property name="name" type="string">
            <column name="NAME"></column>
        </property> 

        <one-to-one name="locker" class="com.avinash.dto.Locker" cascade="all" constrained="true">
        </one-to-one>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Locker POJO Class

```
public class Locker {
    private Long lockerId;
    private String location;
    ...
}
```

Locker.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.avinash.dto.Locker" table="LOCKER">
    <id name="lockerId" type="long" column="LOCKER_ID">
        <generator class="native"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="location" type="string">
        <column name="LOCATION"></column>
    </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Following is my main class to save the student and locker object.

public class OneToOneUnidirectionalPK {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionfactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    Locker locker = new Locker();
    locker.setLocation("320, Building 1, First Floor");

    Student student = new Student();
    student.setName("Avinash");
    student.setLocker(locker);

    Serializable id = session.save(student);
    System.out.println("The id is " + id);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
   HibernateUtil.shutdown();
}
```

When the above java program is executed i get the following error.

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: insert or update on table "student" violates foreign key constraint "fk_fcwupt4ogu22gfes87gv8ctp4"
  Detail: Key (student_id)=(1) is not present in table "locker".

The tables created in postgresSQL are as follows

```
CREATE TABLE student
(
  student_id bigint NOT NULL,
  name character varying(255),
  CONSTRAINT student_pkey PRIMARY KEY (student_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_fcwupt4ogu22gfes87gv8ctp4 FOREIGN KEY (student_id)
      REFERENCES locker (locker_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)

CREATE TABLE locker
(
  locker_id bigint NOT NULL,
  location character varying(255),
  CONSTRAINT locker_pkey PRIMARY KEY (locker_id)
)
```

Why is the data not being inserted here. What is the mistake being done. Can someone please explain.

Answer (score 0):

I think mapping is correct. The problem is with the Database structure:

Please change the DB as below and try:

```
CREATE TABLE student
(
  student_id bigint NOT NULL,
  name character varying(255),
  **locker bigint NOT NULL,**
  CONSTRAINT student_pkey PRIMARY KEY (student_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_fcwupt4ogu22gfes87gv8ctp4 FOREIGN KEY **(locker)**
  REFERENCES locker (locker_id) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

Comment: The tables are created based on the mapping done in .hbm.xml files.I do not want to change the structure of the student table explicitly by executing an alter query or create.Can the database structure be changed through the xml mapping so that the data can be inserted?

Comment: In both the tables there is no realtionship column. Either Student table should contain locker id or locker table should contain student id. How can you relate two tables without any relationship between them.

Comment: There is a locker present in Student POJO and the same is mapped in student.hbm.xml as one to one relation.Am i missing anything that still needs to be added to the mapping. Can you please let me know

Comment: Yes thats right but which column of Student table maps to Locker object. In table definition you have one primary key index and one forign key index but no column mapped with LOCKER_ID. Thats why I added one column named locker which will store locked_id from Locker table and changed the foreign key constraint accordingly.

Comment: As suggested i have changed the student.hbm.xml as follows '<id name="id" type="long" column="ID">
<generator class="foreign">
<param name="property">locker</param>
</generator>
</id>' . This change works fine. But i dont see any changes in the table structure. I dont see this line  **locker bigint NOT NULL,** as mentioned by you in the newly created table

Comment: And one more doubt is that as i have changed the student.hbm.xml to form the relation. Does that make it a bidirectional relation. or is it unidirectional ?

Comment: Please refer to http://www.javatpoint.com/one-to-one-mapping-in-hibernate-by-one-to-one-example